# Android : RecyclerView row Visibility not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am developing an android app (Android Studio). I want to implement `Visibility` GONE/VISIBLE in every row. In the image there are three `recyclerView` rows,

**I want to do the following things :**

There are two part in every row **Heading** & **Details**.

1. When This Activity open all the rows details should hide.
2. When I click on particular row , details of the row should appear by 
   Visibility VISIBLE.
3. When i again click on row details should disappear by Visibility GONE.

   Problem is : If i clicked on first row, Details of first row is showing and 
   without hiding details of first row when click on next any row Heading. I have 
   to click two times to show the details of the next row or Hide the details of 
   next row.

   [Image One Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGqKb.jpg)

   [Image Two Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziZ7m.jpg)

**Adapter Code :**

```
int i = 0;
holder.salt_head_ll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                i++;
                if (i % 2 == 1) {
                    holder.have_show_ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.l1_arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.down_arrow_black);

                } else if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    holder.have_show_ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.l1_arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.right_arrow_black);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: make item with another layout attached with your view, and on item click handle the visibility of layout

Comment: In the image mentioned 3 rows are RecyclerView Rows. How can i Achieve ?

Comment: on your bindviewHolder you will get item position use that position to control only single item

Comment: Can You show your suggestion by code @ĜüptåŠhãsĥwæt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can achieve it without extended listView

**Your card or itemView will be something like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        />

    <!--this is your detail view layout, modify it accordingly-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="detail goes here\n and here\n and here"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#747474"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**YOUR adapter**

```
public class SecondAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SecondAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private List<TextBean> data;
    private Context context;

    public SecondAdapter(Context context, List<TextBean> data){
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_second, parent , false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final TextBean textBean = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(textBean.getTitle());
        if(textBean.isVisibility())
            holder.detailLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            holder.detailLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(textBean.isVisibility()){
                    textBean.setVisibility(false);
                    holder.detailLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
                    textBean.setVisibility(true);
                    holder.detailLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView title;
        public LinearLayout detailLayout;
        public ViewHolder(View item){
            super(item);

            title = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            detailLayout = (LinearLayout) item.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        }

    }
}
```

**YOUR BEAN class**
I have taken only title into account you can add details here also

```
public class TextBean {

    private String title;
    private boolean visibility; // donot forget this, this is to handle visibility

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(boolean visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }
}
```

**How to attach this to RecyclerView**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<TextBean> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        populatedata(); // populate your data here
        SecondAdapter secondAdapter = new SecondAdapter(this,data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(secondAdapter);
    }

    public void populatedata(){
        int count = 1;
        TextBean textBean = new TextBean();
        textBean.setTitle("Title"+count);
        textBean.setVisibility(false); // keep them false in beginning
        data.add(textBean);
        count++;

        textBean = new TextBean();
        textBean.setTitle("Title"+count);
        textBean.setVisibility(false);
        data.add(textBean);
        count++;

        textBean = new TextBean();
        textBean.setTitle("Title"+count);
        textBean.setVisibility(false);
        data.add(textBean);
        count++;

        textBean = new TextBean();
        textBean.setTitle("Title"+count);
        textBean.setVisibility(false);
        data.add(textBean);
        count++;

        textBean = new TextBean();
        textBean.setTitle("Title"+count);
        textBean.setVisibility(false);
        data.add(textBean);
        count++;

        textBean = new TextBean();
        textBean.setTitle("Title"+count);
        textBean.setVisibility(false);
        data.add(textBean);
        count++;
    }
}
```

final answer will look like
[image]

this is the complete solution. if there are any doubts you can ask.

Comment: have you included it in your `textbean` take a look at my bean there is a boolean variable

Comment: This code is tested, it won't show errors, you need to modify few things according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion, instead of using `RecyclerView`, you have to try `ExpandableListView`. The example for `ExpandableListView` is [here](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) and if you want single child in list then set:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your Suggestion @shailesh

Answer (score 0):

First off all make a clicklistener of your adapter by following procedure:

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (clicklistener != null) {
                clicklistener.itemClicked("adapter intials", view, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    public void setClickListener(RecycleListener clicklistener) {
        this.clicklistener = clicklistener;
    }}
```

make a interface class:

```
    // interface designed to handle list view click events
public interface RecycleListener {

    // adapterPage argument for identifying the adapter it is clicked from.
    void itemClicked(String adapterPage, View view, int position);
//    public void selfItemClicked(View view, int position);
}
```

Then in your activity implements with this RecycleListener
it will give you override method

```
@Override
    public void itemClicked(final String adapterType, View view, final int position) {
    //here control visibility of your layout using position and view
    // find your view using this view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a flag in the code and based on that add logic of visiblity in onBindViewHolder.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.linearLayoutItemButton.setVisibility(canShow(productOrderList.get(position))?
            View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
holder.addButton.setVisibility(canShow(productOrderList.get(position))?
            View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
```